# If block executes 2nd command on false

Tags: linux, bash

I am a bash newbie (a PHP dev posing as a Linux sysadmin).
I have the following if block in a bash script:

```
 if [ "$DAY"=="Sunday" ];
 then
 cp /Drive_D/videos_bu/daily/$TODAY /Drive_D/videos_bu/weekly/$WEEK
 printf "\n==========\nWeekly Backup - $TODAY SUCCESS!\n==========\n\n" >> $LOG
 fi
```

The printf line executes even when the test command is false.
Can anyone tell me why?

TIA

Roger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the fact that you don't have the operator, and operands delimited by spaces, the interpreter assumes the whole item as a string, which is different than the empty string, and it goes to the `then` branch. Modify your condition to:

```
if [ "$DAY" == "Sunday" ];
```

in order to get the expected result. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts)'s a useful post.

Comment: ahhh! Thanks. I'll give that a go. Thanks much.

Comment: BTW, I recommend using a single `=` in `[ ]`, since it's more portable. bash allows `==`, but if you're writing for bash (not just any old POSIX shell), you might as well use the cleaner `[[ ]]` form of conditional instead (see [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)).